# camel route for opc-ua milo project

Tags: eclipse, apache-camel, opc-ua, milo

I am working on creating a Camel, Spring boot application that implements the OPC-UA connection. Till now, I was successfully able to run the examples obtained from [Eclipse milo github repository](https://github.com/eclipse/milo).

Now, my task is to create a camel route that will connect to the opc-ua server that is running on a different machine, read data from there and store in a jms queue.

Till now, I am able to run the **BrowseNodeExample** and **ReadNodeExample** where I am connecting to a server simulator *(Top Server V6)*. In the example code, when connecting to the server, the endpoint of the server is given as - `"opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49384/SWToolbox.TOPServer.V6"`

Now in the camel routing piece of code, in the `.configure()` part, what shall I write in the `.from()` part. The piece of code is as -

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49384/SWToolbox.TOPServer.V6")
        .process(opcConnection)
        .split(body().tokenize(";"))
        .to(opcBean.getKarafQueue());
    }
```

While searching for the solution I came across one option: `milo-server:tcp://127.0.0.1:49384/SWToolbox.TOPServer.V6/nodeId=2&amp;namespaceUri=http://examples.freeopcua.github.io`. I tried that but it didn't work. In both the cases I get the below error:

> ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: *(endpoint
>   given)* due to: No component found with scheme: milo-server *(or
>   opc.tcp)*

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add the camel-opc component to your project.

I've found one on [Github](https://github.com/summitsystemsinc/camel-opc/tree/master/camel-opc)

and also milo version on [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.dentrassi.camel.milo) for the OPC-UA connection.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I tried your approach with making my own few changes, like - 
I needed MiloServerEndpoint and got the file from https://github.com/ctron/de.dentrassi.camel.milo/tree/master/camel-milo 
Now since I was working on a different project that needed this code so I added camel-milo's dependency and try to run again which gave me the errors like - 
1) **Cannot auto create component: milo-server**
2) **Invalid URI, no component registered for scheme: milo-server**
3) **Expected property is missing: class**
I am looking into it, but if you have any idea about it then pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The ResolveEndpointFailedException is quite clear, Camel cannot find the component. That means that the auto-discovery failed to load the definition in the META-INF directory.

Have you checked that the camel-milo jar is contained in your fat-jar/war?

As a workaround you can add the component manualy via

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
context.addComponent("foo", new FooComponent(context));
```

http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-add-a-component.html

or in your case

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    getContext().addComponent("milo-server", new org.apache.camel.component.milo.server.MiloServerComponent());

    from("milo-server:tcp://127.0.0.1:49384/SWToolbox.TOPServer.V6/nodeId=2&amp;namespaceUri=http://examples.freeopcua.github.io")
    ...
}
```

Furthermore be aware that milo-server starts an OPC UA server. As I understood your question you want to connect to an OPC UA server. Therefore you need the milo-client component.

[camel-milo client at github](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-milo/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/milo/client)